# Bought Windows 7 Family Pack, where can I download the iso?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

I just asked my brother, who's in the US to buy me a copy of Windows 7 Home Premium Family pack.  It's gonna take a while to mail the package to me here in Hong Kong.  So, I just asked him to email the key to me.  Is there any way to download the DVD ISO somewhere? I heard pre-orders online can get it this way.  Will I be able to download the ISO as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Windows 7 ISO x86 and x64 Official Direct Download Links (Ultimate, Professional and Home Premium)](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/10/windows-7-iso-x86-and-x64-official-direct-download-links-ultimate-professional-and-home-premium/).

Comment: Links don't seem to work :S

Comment: Do they need me to be a member or something?

Comment: I just tried it in a virtual machine, and it still worked. Which link is not working and why?

Comment: yes, obsolete hyperlink

Comment: Here is the link from the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20091113180329/http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/10/windows-7-iso-x86-and-x64-official-direct-download-links-ultimate-professional-and-home-premium/), although it might not be very useful today. This  answer dates from 2009!

Answer (score 1):

You are only able to get ISOs if you purchased online. If you purchased a boxed copy, you have to wait for it to arrive.

I can not 100% guarantee it will work, but, if you have a Technet or MSDN subscription, you can download that media then use your new serial key.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.. Unfortunately I don't have a Technet or MSDN subscription, so that's out.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ask your brother to make the dvds into ISO and just upload them online for you to download.

1. software to make ISO: [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)
2. Transfer File: [Fileai](http://fileai.com/) (No Size limit) or [DepositFiles](http://depositfiles.com/en/) (2GB limit)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my brother is just visiting in the US and his computer doesn't have an optical drive.. So that's out.. Thanks anyway :)